# Mysql - how to compare date in string with unix time in query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have column `view_to_date` in a MySQL table  where is date in format `'04.05.2015'`.

I want to select items where view_to_date < current time.
Is there some way to do it?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date then start fixing your table so your dates are stored as NATIVE date/time values, instead of (useless) strings.

Comment: `str_to_date('04.05.2015','%d.%m.%Y') < curdate()`

Comment: could also be this depending on if it's m/d/y or d/m/y as mentioned above `str_to_date('04.05.2015','%m.%d.%Y') < curdate()`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM test_date WHERE   str_to_date(view_to_date,'%d.%m.%Y') < curdate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the string you have to a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  STR(view_to_date, '%d.%m.%T') < CURRENT_DATE()
```